# How this casting different?

Tags: c

Can any one please explain this line for me .. i am new to c.

```
float *ptr1=(float *)1000;
```

here consider *ptr will have the value 1000. did this (float *) is creating a memory for the pointer value *ptr?

what is the use of casting here ?

Comment: The code you wrote is not semantically correct C. Please find and read a good book on the subject, such as "The C Programming Language" by the creators of the language.

Comment: @user4815162342: actually this type expression has always been quite common in embedded or "bare metal" applications, where you need to access absolute addresses.

Comment: @user4815162342 I would strongly recommend to avoid that book at all costs. It is better to find a book from someone who is up to date with the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin The book was just an example. The point of the comment is that StackOverflow is not a substitute for tutorials and other learning materials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of code won't set `*ptr` to `1000.0f`, it will make `ptr` *point to* the address `1000`.  What this means is architecture specific, as you are forcing a pointer to point to some exact place and how a processor interprets addresses is, again, architecture specific.

The casting tells the compiler that the value `1000` is a pointer to a `float`, i.e. an address.

If you want to have a pointer to `float`, and have it point to some other location that contain the value `1000.0f`, then you need to declare another variable and use the address-of operator `&`:

```
float flt1 = 1000.0f;
float *ptr1 = &flt1;
```

Important note: The lifetime of the `flt1` variable in the above example must be the same (or longer) as the lifetime of the variable `ptr1`, or you will have a stray pointer which could lead to *undefined behavior*.  This means a pointer pointing to somewhere that has ceased to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your cast says "treat 1000 as the address of a float" and assign that address to ptr1. That is, you have a pointer, but you don't have any float to point it to. 1000 is just a value that could be used to initialise a float, but you have to actually store that value somewhere before you can point to it.

```
float   f = 1000;
float*  ptr1 = &f;
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of casting is usually found in embedded applications, where you have absolute hard-coded addresses, such as memory-mapped I/O ports.

```
float *ptr1=(float *)1000;
```

This defines a pointer to absolute address 1000 (decimal). Reading or writing to that address will attempt to read or write a float value.